# Uninstalling program with no uninstall option

Tags: windows, uninstall, control-panel

For Symantec Endpoint Protection, only the repair button is shown. I however; need to uninstall it.

How can I uninstall it? My user account has administrative rights.

Version is Windows 7

[image]

Comment: Open your command prompt up and run SFC /SCANNOW make sure you have admin rights

Comment: @NetworkKingPin - How is SFC going to allow the user to uninstall Symantec.

Comment: @Sax - You should be using [CleanWipe](https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.HOWTO74877.html) to remove Symantec Endpoint Protection (SEP).

Comment: He said the option was not there any more so it may be a system issue.

Comment: try this: https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/34758-how-to-manually-uninstall-symantec-endpoint-protection-12-1-client

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you won't or can't go the CleanWipe route, this should restore the Uninstall option. First find SEP's Uninstall key entry by searching under

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

or

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

depending on whether the install is 32- or 64-bit.

Then look for a DWORD value called "NoRemove" -- it should be set to 1. Change to 0 (zero) and refresh Add/Remove. You should now be able to Uninstall as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Symantec recomends using the cleanwipe utility obtained from here

https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.HOWTO74877.html

In the CleanWipe folder, double-click CleanWipe.exe, and click Next.
Accept the license agreement and click Next.
Select the Symantec products you want to remove and click Next twice.
When the tool finishes running, you may be prompted to restart the computer.
After the computer restarts, CleanWipe reopens and continues to run.
Click Next.
Click Finish. The Symantec products you selected are now uninstalled.

CleanWipe is obtained from your support contract.

https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.TECH103088.html